# Bind two attributes to the same line in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to bind two attributes of class to ListView so that they are in same line(somehow combine them).
Example:
FirstName: John
LastName: Potter
Desired output in ListView: John Potter

```
    <ListView x:Name="lvPersons">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: You could make that stackpanel orientation horizontal `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">`

Comment: Already tried that, but if I do that, space is not recognized. I get JohnPotter as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from using *StackPanel* with horizontal orientation (and apropriate margins), you may also use [Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run) sections like this:

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
    <Run Text=" "/>
    <Run Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Note that you may also put there more things if you need - *HyperLinks*, *LineBreaks* and more, the advantage is that they will use formatting of the *TextBlock*.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! That space(" ") between FirstName and LastName is not needed in this solution, so if you want you can edit your answer.

Comment: @pisk1 Watch out with this space - I've notified different behavior in debug/release version with this spaces - also check if you don't have additional spaces in FirstName and LastName.